# Unable to get AJAX response as JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using JQuery's ajax function, I am getting data in the *attempted* form of a javascript object, and wanting to use it as a global variable for future use. My problem is that when I try to receive the data as a javascript object it is unaccessible, but when I return it as plain text, it returns and is usable as a string. I can see in the developer options that the data is returned, and correctly laid out, but I still cannot use it in the console.

What can I do to go from only getting a string, to having a usable object?

**Perl**

These are the content-type headers I'm using in the script called.

```
if(!$in{type}){
    print "content-type: text/html \n\n";
}
elsif($in{type} eq "json"){
    print "content-type: application/json \n\n";
}
elsif($in{type} eq "script"){
    print "content-type: application/javascript \n\n";
}
```

**JS**

```
var menuItems;
function getMenuItems(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "js/sporkAjax.pl",
        datatype: "script", /*Also tried json, which wasn't much better*/
        data: {func: "getMenuItems", type: "script"},
        success: function(data){
            menuItems = data;
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

and the literal response is

```
{
    Beer: {
        IDs: [4,5],
        Names: ['A Beer','B Beer'],
        LargeCost: [5.00,7.00],
        SmallCost: [2.50,3.50]
    },
    Wine: {
        IDs: [1,2,3],
        Names: ['Big Wine','Small Wine','Woweee'],
        LargeCost: [4.00,8.00,5.00],
        SmallCost: [2.00,4.00,2.50]
    },
    Plate: {
        IDs: [6],
        Names: ['Fish'],
        Cost: [12.00],
        AllowTemps: [0]
    }
}
```

Here is screencap of the output when datatype is left default.
[image: Screencap of output]

Comment: have you tried to parse the string to a JSON object -> var myData = JSON.parse(data); ??

Comment: You'll get more information here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var menuItems;
function getMenuItems(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "js/sporkAjax.pl",
        datatype: "script", /*Also tried json, which wasn't much better*/
        data: {func: "getMenuItems", type: "script"},
        success: function(data){
            menuItems = data;
            // You parse the string into an Object
            const obj = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(obj.Beer.IDs);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I had to remove the datatype, and type: "script", but this worked. Thank you.